# Can't delete old relations between 2 entities

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using spring data on my project. I want to update relations between 2 entities. I have this code (Not is real entities). Code examples are simplifications.

```
PollEntity pe = pollEntityRepository.findById(peId);
for(PollQuestion qe : pe.getQuestions()){
   qe.setAnswers(answerList); 
}
pollEntityRepository.save(pe );
```

I have a PollEntity with 1question and 7 answers. Now, I have a new list of 2 answers that I want update. The code executes without errors but I continue having 7 relations to my question instead only 2.

These are my entities relations:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "POLL_QUESTION")
public class PollQuestion implements Serializable {
    @Id anotations
    private BigDecimal id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pollQuestion", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    private List<PollAnswer> pollAnswers;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "POLL_ANSWER")
public class PollAnswer implements Serializable {
    @Id anotations
    private BigDecimal id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private PollQuestion pollQuestion;
    
}
```